# Node Sequelize Relational Challenge

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have three tables (all associated model classnames use PascalCase)

```
schools                school_codes              course
------                 ------                    ------
id (pk)                code (pk)                 name
name                   school_id (fk)            school_code (fk)
```

I'm trying to define sequelize relations, so that this Course lookup returns the associated School:

```
const courseWithSchool = await models.Course.findOne({
  include: [{
    model: models.School,
    required: true,
  }],
})
```

The mysql for this is very simple.

```
mysql> select c.*, s.* from courses c inner join school_codes sc on c.school_code = sc.code inner join schools s on s.id = sc.school_id;
```

How do I define the relations in sequelize models (without modifying existing schema)? Thanks!

Here are the model definitions I have:

**schools.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const School = sequelize.define('School', {
   name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'schools' })  
  return School
}
```

**course.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    school_code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,  
        references: {
          model: 'school_codes',
          key: 'code',
        }
      }
  }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'courses' })  
  return Course
}
```

**schoolcode.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const SchoolCode = sequelize.define('SchoolCode', {
    code:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'courses',  
        key: 'school_code'
      }
    },
    school_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,  
      references: {
        model: 'schools',  
        key: 'id',
      },    
    },    
  }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'school_codes', })     
  return SchoolCode
}
```

*I'm just looking for the relations to add to the bottom of each model definition - example...*

```
  // School.associate = function (models) {
  //   School.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
  //     through: 'school_codes',
  //     foreignKey: 'school_id',
  //     otherKey: 'code'
  //   })
  // }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can keep association in its respective model. I prefer to keep association in respective master table rather than mapping table. The idea is to associate `source` model to `target` model and its relationship in both direction. For example let us say source model `School` has one `SchoolCode` target model and its reverse relation

```
//school.model.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const School = sequelize.define('school', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'schools' })  
        
    School.associate = function ({SchoolCode, Course}) {
        School.hasOne(SchoolCode, {
            foreignKey: 'school_id',
        })
        SchoolCode.belongsTo(School, {foreignKey: 'school_id'})
        School.belongsToMany(Course, { through: SchoolCode , foreignKey : 'school_id'}); //added new
    }
    return School;
}

//course.model.js 
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Course = sequelize.define('course', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      school_code: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,  
          references: {
            model: 'school_codes',
            key: 'code',
          }
        }
    }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'courses' })  
    
    Course.associate = function ({SchoolCode, School}) {
        Course.hasMany(SchoolCode, {
            foreignKey: 'code',
        })
        Course.belongsToMany(School, { through: SchoolCode,  foreignKey : 'code'}); //added new
    }
    return Course;
  }
```

Finally the third model of `SchoolCode` (Mapping table).
Note that we don't have to add a reference `school_code`. It is a primaryKey `code` of same table. We use `references` mainly to define the foreign keys, no need for reverse definition here.
Hence **commented** that part from code below.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const SchoolCode = sequelize.define('SchoolCode', {
      code:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
     // references: {
     //   model: 'courses',  
     //   key: 'school_code'
     // }
      },
      school_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,  
        references: {
          model: 'school',  
          key: 'id',
        },    
      },    
    }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'school_codes', }) 
    
    return SchoolCode
  }
```

References : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Comment: Having trouble piecing together all of these things. I already have the models defined, I'm just looking to add the proper relational definition to the model... Unsure what these should look like.

Comment: I updated my original Q. I don't need to init a connection or anything... just looking for the associations.

Comment: I have update my answer. please let me know for any issues/concerns

Comment: "SchoolCode.belongsToMany(Course) requires through option, pass either a string or a model"

Comment: I'm giving up on this. This should not be so difficult.

Comment: Also, running this `await models.Course.findOne({include: [{model: models.School, required: true}]})` results in "SequelizeEagerLoadingError: School is not associated to Course!"

Comment: I am looking into belongToMany issue, will get back on this. But regarding above issue, in this case the course as mentioned in question was associated with `school_codes` with its Foreign Key as `code`. The school table and courses tables are not related directly right? hence we are getting this issue.

Comment: We don't need `belongsToMany` association. I am commenting it out in answer. The reason is school_codes is already a junction of school and courses table(though created manually). `belongsToMany` expects to create such junction(map) mandatory between `course` and `school_codes` which is not required in our case hence, we can remove it. My bad for not identifying it previously.

Comment: Made those changes. Running the findOne above (`models.Course.findOne`) results in "School is not associated to Course!"...

Comment: Is there a different way i should be querying for Course with the associated School? I just used the 'include' property as shown in my OP.

Comment: We have defined relations one to one (for eg : school to school_codes). Seems like sequelize needs mapping junction/schema relation to query course through school. I have added it to code with comments `added new`.
Reference : https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/
 Please let me know if this helps or wanna discuss more on this :) ..... don't wanna drag it more so feel free to  --points if not useful :(

Answer (score 1):

You can define relations like

```
SchoolCode.belongsTo(School, { foreignKey: 'school_id', targetKey: 'id' });
Course.belongsTo(SchoolCode, { foreignKey: 'school_code', targetKey: 'code' });
```